# ESP32 (ESP - WROOM - 32) Brownout detector was triggered

Tags: arduino

I am trying to use an esp chip stand alone and I have issue with resetting the chip when try to run anything that use wifi.
If I upload a simple code like read A0 or blink is working fine. If I try anything that use WiFi the chip is resetting over and over with the error : "Brownout detector was triggered "
Searching google send me on power supply issues for this error, but I powered using 3.3V rail from a ATX power supply so I really doubt that I have power issues.
Schematic I used - esp-periph.png

[image]

Breadboard build - esp32-bread-board.jpg

[image]

GND of ftdi adapter (which is set to 3.3V) is common to the one from ATX power supply.

Findings :

1 - If I use esp idf tools ("make flash" , "esptool.py --chip esp32 -p com23 erase_flash") uploading code and erasing flash is working fine.

2 - If I use Arduino IDE, uploads the code but get that error at the end - arduino-err.png

[image]

The error I get in the monitor after upload any code using wifi (scan wifi example from express if examples folder) :

```
    Brownout detector was triggered

ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:6468
load:0x40078000,len:11304
load:0x40080400,len:6780
entry 0x40080768
I (29) boot: ESP-IDF v4.0-dev-667-gda13efc17 2nd stage bootloader
I (29) boot: compile time 18:24:09
I (29) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...
I (35) boot: SPI Speed      : 80MHz
I (39) boot: SPI Mode       : DIO
I (43) boot: SPI Flash Size : 4MB
I (47) boot: Partition Table:
I (51) boot: ## Label            Usage          Type ST Offset   Length
I (58) boot:  0 nvs              WiFi data        01 02 00009000 00006000
I (66) boot:  1 phy_init         RF data          01 01 0000f000 00001000
I (73) boot:  2 factory          factory app      00 00 00010000 00100000
I (81) boot: End of partition table
I (85) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=0x00010020 vaddr=0x3f400020 size=0x17af0 ( 97008) map
I (122) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0x00027b18 vaddr=0x3ffb0000 size=0x03014 ( 12308) load
I (126) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0x0002ab34 vaddr=0x40080000 size=0x00400 (  1024) load
0x40080000: _WindowOverflow4 at C:/msys32/home/admin/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/xtensa_vectors.S:1779

I (129) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0x0002af3c vaddr=0x40080400 size=0x050d4 ( 20692) load
I (145) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=0x00030018 vaddr=0x400d0018 size=0x67418 (422936) map
0x400d0018: _stext at ??:?

I (269) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0x00097438 vaddr=0x400854d4 size=0x0a7d8 ( 42968) load
0x400854d4: get_rate_fcc_index at ??:?

I (294) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000
I (294) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...
I (295) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
I (299) cpu_start: Application information:
I (303) cpu_start: Project name:     scan
I (308) cpu_start: App version:      1
I (312) cpu_start: Compile time:     Jun  4 2019 18:24:21
I (319) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  a1d971f1d84e4534...
I (325) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v4.0-dev-667-gda13efc17
I (331) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x4008105c
0x4008105c: call_start_cpu1 at C:/msys32/home/admin/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32/cpu_start.c:267

I (323) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (341) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (348) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM
I (354) heap_init: At 3FFB8EB0 len 00027150 (156 KiB): DRAM
I (361) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (367) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
I (373) heap_init: At 4008FCAC len 00010354 (64 KiB): IRAM
I (380) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (173) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (234) wifi: wifi driver task: 3ffc0828, prio:23, stack:3584, core=0
I (234) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE
I (234) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE
I (254) wifi: wifi firmware version: e11ccc4
I (254) wifi: config NVS flash: enabled
I (254) wifi: config nano formating: disabled
I (254) wifi: Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32
I (264) wifi: Init data frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (264) wifi: Init management frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (274) wifi: Init management short buffer num: 32
I (274) wifi: Init static rx buffer size: 1600
I (284) wifi: Init static rx buffer num: 10
I (284) wifi: Init dynamic rx buffer num: 32
W (294) phy_init: failed to load RF calibration data (0x1102), falling back to full calibration

Brownout detector was triggered
```

Any help really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unbelievable but he atx power supply, even if I measured 3.3V on that rail seems was not actually worked for some reason without any other consumer....if I add a consumer on 5V rail then is working fine. I also tested with esp32 powered from an arduino mega 3.3v and is fine...so can close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable but he atx power supply, even if I measured 3.3V on that rail seems was not actually worked for some reason without any other consumer....if I add a consumer on 5V rail then is working fine. I also tested with esp32 powered from an arduino mega 3.3v and is fine...so can close this